# Dynamic Bootstrap Carousel 3 items as Active

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to create a dynamic carousel in angular js and would like to have 3 items in each slide. the issue is that the first 3 items should be wrapped around the "active" class and all the next items in groups of 3 should be wrapped around the "item" class. I tried using JQuery but it is not giving me the intended behaviour.

html code using ng-repeat

```
<div class='col-md-8'>
    <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
                <div id="id" class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="cards">
                        <img ng-src="{{:: item.imageUrl}}" />
                     </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button data-slide="prev" ng-show="items.length > 3" class="left carousel-control" ng-click="shiftLeft()"></button>
        <button data-slide="next" ng-show="items.length > 3" class="right carousel-control" ng-click="shiftRight()"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the code to look something like this (static representation of the intended code).

```
       <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item  active">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="cards"><img alt="" src="img1"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="cards"><img alt="" src="img2"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="cards"><img alt="" src="img3"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="cards"><img alt="" src="img4"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="cards"><img alt="" src="img5"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="cards"><img alt="" src="img6"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="cards"><img alt="" src="img7"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="cards"><img alt="" src="img8"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="cards"><img alt="" src="img9"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: These may help you :

link 1 :
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp
link 2:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp